# R development Mac and Windows

Tags: r

Hi all looking to reach out to other R developers.  I am struggle to design cross functionality in windows and mac.  I am using getGraphicsEvent to program in keyboard shortcuts for different apps i am developing.

What are my options to do this in mac?

If this is possible;

How do i get faster plotting on mac?

Below is an example of how i use this.

```
readkeygraph <- function(prompt)
{
    getGraphicsEvent(prompt = prompt, 
             onMouseDown = NULL, onMouseMove = NULL,
             onMouseUp = NULL, onKeybd = onKeybd,
             consolePrompt = "uh")
Sys.sleep(0.01)
return(keyPressed)
}

onKeybd <- function(key)
{
keyPressed <<- key
}

keyPressed <- readkeygraph("[press any key to continue]")

if(keyPressed=="c")
    {print("yo")}
```

Comment: I'd seriously consider moving to Shiny for app development.